# CRM Online 2013 not printing a barcode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a `FetchXML` report for `CRM Online` and I have an ID field that is converted to a barcode using `Barcode 39`. When I run the report from `CRM Online` it shows the barcode in the report but when I print it, it comes out as plain text.

I have no idea what the issue is. The barcode is installed on my machine. When I export the report to Words it prints fine but when I print it from CRM it comes out as plain text.

Any help guys?

**Print from CRM**
  [image]

**Report in CRM with barcode showing**
[image]

Comment: can you add some screenshots?

Comment: here you go @Guido Preite. I don't see why CRM is not printing a barcode. I have the font on my machine and its working fine if i print if from MS Word or directly from BIDS

Comment: I know Community you are out there. Is it even possible to print barcodes in a report in CRM Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the report is being generated on the Online SSRS server, custom fonts (like your barcode font) aren't available:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44c9e97a-dde0-48e3-854a-fcb21df7d149/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-fonts-in-ssrs-reports-crm-2011-online?forum=crm

Comment: Daryl is there another way of printing barcodes on CRM Online then?

Comment: @hkhan CRM is constrained by the limitations of SSRS.  I'm not versed enough on SSRS to be able to answer that definitively.  I would assume there would be someway to create the barcode as an image, and get that to print in SSRS, but I don't know.

Comment: i can convert the barcode in image in SSRS. But that requires custom code and CRM Online does not allow custom code in reports.